# Why is Heroku rejecting this git push?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku

I make a new Heroku app inside of my current app directory using `Heroku create` and ran this:

```
MyMac:bodb pawel$ git push heroku master
Counting objects: 359, done.
Delta compression using up to 2 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (291/291), done.
Writing objects: 100% (359/359), 13.83 MiB | 2 KiB/s, done.
Total 359 (delta 40), reused 0 (delta 0)

 !     Heroku push rejected due to an unrecognized error.
 !     We've been notified, see http://support.heroku.com if the problem persists.

To git@heroku.com:myproject.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@heroku.com:myproject.git'
```

My rails app runs on Ruby `1.8.7` but even a Heroku app on `--stack bamboo-ree-1.8.7` fails.

I have also run `bundle install` and my Gemfile is up to date.

Comment: pre-receive hook declined -> contact Heroku support

Comment: What does "pre-receive hook declined" mean?

Comment: @Simpleton: Git has hooks that tie into various phases of the version control process. You can use them to run custom scripts, e.g. for removing passwords, automatically minifying JS before pushing etc: http://progit.org/book/ch7-3.html Regarding `pre-receive`: "The first script to run when handling a push from a client is pre-receive. It takes a list of references that are being pushed from stdin; if it exits non-zero, none of them are accepted."

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't know why the commit was corrupted, but contacted Heroku and they sorted it out.

Comment: I just contacted heroku support with my problem. How to know when they reply back ? could you please let me know ?

Comment: I think anywhere between a couple of hours and 2-3 days.

Answer (score 2):

I had that error once when I changed the Gemfile but did not run bundler and therefore modified Gemfile.lock

Comment: Had this same error, and it was because I added a gem, forgot to bundle install, and only attempted to push the Gemfile to Heroku, and not Gemfile.lock.