# git, Heroku: pre-receive hook declined

Tags: ruby, git, heroku, rack

I am in the process of setting up a git repository and attempting to link it to Heroku. When I run the command

```
git push heroku master
```

I receive

```
Counting objects: 7, done.
Delta compression using up to 2 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (5/5), done.
Writing objects: 100% (7/7), 714 bytes, done.
Total 7 (delta 1), reused 0 (delta 0)

-----> Heroku receiving push

 !     Heroku push rejected due to an unrecognized error.
 !     We've been notified, see http://support.heroku.com if the problem persists.


To git@heroku.com:morning-stream-3712.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@heroku.com:morning-stream-3712.git'
```

How can I get my application pushed to Heroku?

Comment: Related to this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7688262/why-is-heroku-rejecting-this-git-push

Comment: always check https://status.heroku.com/ there have been platform errors today.

Comment: @John: They're platforms have consistently had errors almost every day for the last month, it wasn't just today.  I would just try pushing again later.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Make sure you are pushing a repo that contains a proper supported app ( Rails, Django etc.) and you are not just pushing some random repo to test it out.

[Newbie in Heroku: Error when push my app to Heroku](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8165028/newbie-in-heroku-error-when-push-my-app-to-heroku/8171155#8171155)

If that is not the case and you are pushing what you think is a valid app, contact Heroku support and they will fix it for you.

Comment: You got it, that was the issue. "Hello Rack!" successfully prints to the screen when you visit http://morning-stream-3712.heroku.com/ :)

Comment: Thanks! "package.json" was needed so that heroku knows it's a node app.

Comment: For me I had to do:
Heroku logs
in cmd
and then I saw the REAL error - I had too many heroku remotes. Spent 5 days on it - really. You welcome

Comment: Thanks! Also it's important for Heroku to push some secrets.json even if they were already there.

Answer (score 17):

Make sure that you are using either npm or yarn.lock file-

Two different lockfiles found: package-lock.json and yarn.lock
       Both npm and yarn have created lockfiles for this application,
       but only one can be used to install dependencies.

After deleting yarn.lock and pushing the code again to git, my issue resolved.

Comment: I faced the same problem, removing  package-lock.json  and pushing the code again to git my issue resolved, Thanks.

Comment: why is the package-lock causing issues though?

Answer (score 13):

Deleting package-lock.json solved it for me

Comment: for me it was addig package-lock.json to my commit

Answer (score 8):

First, disable collectstatic:

```
heroku config:set DISABLE_COLLECTSTATIC=1
```

Then run:

```
git push heroku master
```

For more details and full steps, [check here](https://github.com/thuahahadi/upload-and-update-django-project-on-heroku).

Answer (score 5):

I faced the same problem:

```
! [remote rejected] vX.X.XX -> master (pre-receive hook declined) 
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@heroku.com:[application-name]'
```

I realized that my heroku application Stack is 'cedar-10' and was deprecated from 04/11/2014 and disabled from 04/11/2015 ([Cedar-14 is now Generally Available](https://devcenter.heroku.com/changelog-items/550)).

The solution was to upgrade the heroku application Stack following the guide:

[Upgrading the production app to Cedar-14](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/cedar-14-migration#upgrading-the-production-app-to-cedar-14)

Answer (score 4):

**Another issue could be that in a production environment, you can't use sqlite3**, the default database when you make a rails app.

In order to fix this, just change the database your rails app uses to Postgres. This can easily be accomplished by **editing your Gemfile**

From your Gemfile, remove:

```
gem sqlite3;
```

and add the following:

```
group :development, :test do
  gem 'sqlite3'
end

group :production do
  gem 'pg'
end
```

Comment: you should always use the same database type for local and production environments. Otherwise you cannot be sure, if some db specific stuff is a problem

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem but with a Django app, it turned out that pip wasn't able to download/install one of the dependencies of the requirements.txt file (it was eyeD3)

Answer (score 1):

If you have an error in your css this error can also show up.

In one of my media queries I put

```
@media screen adn (min-width: 1000px) {
```

Instead of the "and" which gave me this error.

A good indicator that this may be the case is if you get an error that contains the message

```
"Tasks: TOP => assets:precompile ... Precompiling assets failed"
```

That was my first clue to look in my css.

Answer (score 1):

A little late to the game, one of my issues was I had an outdated **sshkey**. Just need to update that in the settings.

Another thing was I was pushing Python Django CMS, and it was running `python manage.py collectstatic` during deploy and it was failing. So make sure you check the log `heroku logs --tail`. That gave me another hint to turn off `collectstatic`, it event tells you what to type to turn it off.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem (same error with Heroku):

```
To https://git.heroku.com/myapp.git
 ! [remote rejected]   master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/myapp.git'
```

**The mistake**
I made some changes to my code and removed some parameters, apparently I missed a simple comma (,) on a line. This caused a build error. Which was not visible in the console upon pushing, only the "pre-receive hook declined" error.

**SOLUTION**
I fixed the comma issue, rebuild and pushed to Heroku and now it works.

Answer (score 1):

Came across this same error when deploying a node app, but resolved with these two steps and thought I'd share in case anyone else runs into the same issues.

1. Make sure you aren't committing `node_modules` since heroku installs dependencies from package.json on push. Try adding `node_modules/` to your `.gitignore` to ensure you don't accidentally commit it
2. Heroku uses Node v12 which node-sass 4.10.0 will fail to build with. Try increasing node-sass version by adding the following. This allowed it to build successfully for me:

```
  "devDependencies": {
    "node-sass": "^4.12.0"
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

I decided to read the logs line by line.
Below is part of the error logs:

```
remote:        > gbt-ltd-website-frontend@0.1.0 build /tmp/build_c37edf59
remote:        > react-scripts build
remote:        
remote:        Creating an optimized production build...
remote:        Failed to compile.
remote:        
remote:        Cannot read property 'toLowerCase' of undefined
remote:        CompileError: Begins at CSS selector .Styles_hone__1Uuf2
remote:        
remote:        
remote: npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
remote: npm ERR! errno 1
remote: npm ERR! gbt-ltd-website-frontend@0.1.0 build: `react-scripts build`
remote: npm ERR! Exit status 1
...
remote: !       Push rejected to gbtstructurals.
remote: 
To https://git.heroku.com/gbtstructurals.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/gbtstructurals.git'
```

From where the error started, "npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE" I read up and I found the actual cause of the error. It was a CSS rule. I first removed the rule and it built. Then I checked my declarations and found out I was contradicting myself.

Answer (score 1):

In case if this needs anyone in future even though I am a beginner and doesn't know much about Heroku, you may have requested a version in runtime.txt file which the stack doesn't support.

`python-3.8.2 to python-3.8.10`

Changing from python-3.8.2 to python-3.8.10 helped me solved it. You may see the supported stacks here: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/python-support

Answer (score 1):

My issue is that there was one file which I did not add in my previous git commit. The problem was fixed after I added that last file, and pushed another commit.

When I checked the logs, it showed this error:

```
remote: -----> Build
remote:        Running build
remote:        
remote:        > student-app-frontend@0.1.0 build
remote:        > react-scripts build
remote:        
remote:        Creating an optimized production build...
remote:        Failed to compile.
remote:        
remote:        SassError: File to import not found or unreadable: ../../designUtils/fontDesign.
remote:                on line 2 of src/components/studentCard/StudentCard.scss
remote:        >> @import '../../designUtils/fontDesign.js';
remote:        
remote:           ^
remote:        
remote:        
remote: 
remote: -----> Build failed
```

This shows that Heroku was not able to find the imported file `'designUtils/fontDesign.js'`

This is because I used the command `git commit -am 'latest changes'` instead of using the commands `git add.`, then `git status` to check if everything was added properly, and then `git commit -m 'latest changes'`

Answer (score 0):

i thought , this will not be the error occured due to any app , or code changes.
i have same problem now this happen due to the following reason:

- 1) i have code on bitbucket/git i push the code to repository (this
  repo is linked with the heroku app,meanse changes to this will
  reflects on heroku)
- 2)after pushing code to repo , i am trying to    push code on heroku
  with "git push heroku master" but due to some    reason i abort this
  command, thats why code is not pushed to heroku
- 3)then i am agian triyng to  push code to heroku it says same error
  as above
- 4) the solution for this is "just pull yours last commited      code"
  and push the changes to heroku ..thats it thanks

Answer (score 0):

I had this with a sinatra application. (Heroku does support Sinatra).

The instructions on the heroku blog post were incomplete

https://blog.heroku.com/32_deploy_merb_sinatra_or_any_rack_app_to_heroku

My program ran fine locally but I got that error when trying to push to heroku.

The heroku blogpost didn't include the need to make a gemfile and do bundle install.   The program was running locally fine, but to make it work on heroku it needed a Gemfile and bundle install on it.

this link here https://teamtreehouse.com/community/how-can-i-make-my-sinatra-app-public   mentioned that I needed a Gemfile, and mentioned the contents of the Gemfile. And then to do bundle install. Then once that is done, then follow the instructions on that heroku blog post, of making  the program file, and the config.ru and the git repo and doing heroku create (which also creates the remote), then git push heroku master.

i.e.

Gemfile as mentioned at treehouse link

```
# define our source to look for gems
source "http://rubygems.org/"

# declare the sinatra dependency
gem "sinatra"
```

And bundle install to install that Gemfile.

```
bundle install
```

hello.rb  (as mentioned on heroku blogpost)

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'sinatra'

get '/' do
  "Hello from Sinatra on Heroku!"
end
```

config.ru

```
require './hello'
run Sinatra::Application
```

git

```
$ git init
Initialized empty Git repository in /Users/adam/hello/.git/
$ git add .
$ git commit -m "sinatra and heroku, two great tastes"
[master (root-commit)]: created 93a9e6d: "sinatra and heroku, two great tastes"
 2 files changed, 9 insertions(+), 0 deletions(-)
 create mode 100644 config.ru
 create mode 100644 hello.rb
```

heroku create

```
$ heroku create
Created http://severe-spring-77.heroku.com/ | git@heroku.com:severe-spring-77.git
Git remote heroku added
```

the push to heroku

```
$ git push heroku master
Counting objects: 4, done.
Compressing objects: 100% (3/3), done.
Writing objects: 100% (4/4), 385 bytes, done.
Total 4 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)

-----> Heroku receiving push
-----> Verifying repository integrity... done, looks like a Rack app.
       Compiled slug size is 0.1MB
-----> Launching....... done
       App deployed to Heroku

To git@heroku.com:severe-spring-77.git
 * [new branch]      master -> master
```

Answer (score 0):

For me it was an unused import in java app , removed the unused import and everything built fine.

Answer (score 0):

My issue was I forgot to bundle install before pushing.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had an npm script called "build" that had the as value `npm run build --prefix client`.

Heroku automatically executes the `npm run build` command and it couldn't build my React app. Probably because Heroku didn't install react-scripts module.

So I renamed the command to `build-client` and now I can push the changes to Heroku.

Answer (score 0):

**Checking you config vars (in heroku) may be a good idea.**

I had the same error message, when I created a pipeline for my app and wanted to push to the newly created staging app. It didn't work because the config vars I had previously set were not transferred to the new staging app (obviously). After I added the variables once more, pushing to heroku git worked flawlessly again.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue with a recent application after running:

```
git push heroku master
```

The error:

```
remote:  !     Push failed
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote:
remote: !       Push rejected to stormy-escarpment-13653.
remote:
To https://git.heroku.com/stormy-escarpment-13653.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
```

The problem was that I was in the wrong directory when I ran the command. I needed to be in the root of the application.
So I ran a `git rm --cached <app_name>`, to clean up and the ran again and it worked as expected.

Comment: what if you want to deploy from a subdirectory of a folder that exists on your github

Answer (score 0):

**The steps which work for me**

1: I just remove package-lock.json and yarn.lock
2: user npm install command
3: then push the changes to the github
4: use "git push heroku main" command.

to know more you can visit the below links [enter link description here](https://help.heroku.com/0KU2EM53/why-is-my-node-js-build-failing-because-of-conflicting-lock-files)

Answer (score 0):

For me it solved by this command:

```
git push heroku master --force
```

or

```
git push heroku your_branch_name:master --force
```

Answer (score -1):

Try Updating Node/php or any engines to latest version and then deploy again it will work for sure.

Answer (score -1):

you need to mention the language in the root directory

how I fixed with

my python flask does not mention the requirments.text

Heroku detect the

```
Using buildpack: heroku/python
remote: -----> Python app detected
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DnYXa.png)