# `git push heroku master` returns error

Tags: php, git, heroku

I am trying to create a simple project on Heroku by pushing a git which contains only a php ('Hello World') file, am empty README file and an empty json file.

When I enter `git push heroku master` in the terminal to do this I (partly) get the following response:

```
remote:  !     Push failed due to an unrecognized error, and we've been notified.
remote: 
remote:  !     Please try pushing again.
remote:  !     If the problem persists, see http://help.heroku.com/ and provide Request ID *my_project_id*.
remote: 
remote: 
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote: 
remote: !   Push rejected to *my_project_name*.
remote: 
To https://git.heroku.com/*my_project_name*.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/*my_project_name*.git'
```

Because of this I cannot properly run any new Heroku app (which may include only a php 'Hello World' file).

This error was presented suddenly after I have already  used successfully `git push heroku master` for dozens of heroku apps (the same day).
Actually, this error was presented to me also when I tried to edit an app which was already running properly.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [git, Heroku: pre-receive hook declined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8216586/git-heroku-pre-receive-hook-declined)

Comment: I do think that this is a duplicate: This error was presented suddenly after I have already used successfully git push heroku master for dozens of heroku apps (the same day). Actually, this error was presented to me also when I tried to edit an app which was already running properly.

Comment: I think you're affected by this: https://status.heroku.com/incidents/1460 if it's already working well locally.

Comment: Yes, I am suspecting that this is the reason. As some other people are writing on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8216586/git-heroku-pre-receive-hook-declined, there are many errors in these cloud paltforms. If this is the problem then it is ok for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am pretty sure that I was affected by deployment failures occurring on Heroku itself and it was not anything about what I did which caused this error.

When something goes wrong I tend to think that I am doing something wrong  but sometimes it may be that something wrong is occurring at the other side of my computer.