# trying to push to Heroku

Tags: heroku

```
remote:  !     Push failed
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote: 
remote: !   Push rejected to nameless-ravine-29197.
remote: 
To https://git.heroku.com/nameless-ravine-29197.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/nameless-ravine-29197.git'
```

can anyone helps please?
thank

Comment: Possible duplicate of [git, Heroku: pre-receive hook declined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8216586/git-heroku-pre-receive-hook-declined)

Comment: Please provide the entire build output.

Comment: Thanks this has been solved, issue was on the bundle version, I was using the latest version so had to removed that and install an old version.... I know weird but solved the issue.