# Why is there an error when I try and commit my bot?

Tags: heroku, discord.py

I'm using heroku and I'm trying to deploy my files but I keep getting this error:

```
$ git push heroku master
Enumerating objects: 13, done.
Counting objects: 100% (13/13), done.
Delta compression using up to 16 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (8/8), done.
Writing objects: 100% (13/13), 1.75 KiB | 893.00 KiB/s, done.
Total 13 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 0
remote: Compressing source files... done.
remote: Building source:
remote:
remote: -----> Building on the Heroku-20 stack
remote: -----> App not compatible with buildpack: https://buildpack-registry.s3.amazonaws.com/buildpacks/heroku/python.tgz
remote:        More info: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/buildpacks#detection-failure
remote:
remote:  !     Push failed
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote:
remote: !       Push rejected to botver2554.
remote:
To https://git.heroku.com/botver2554.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/botver2554.git'
```

Can I have some help?
This is different from the suggested questions because I'm getting a buildpack error, and I don't know what it is.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [git, Heroku: pre-receive hook declined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8216586/git-heroku-pre-receive-hook-declined)

Comment: No, my problem is about something called "Buildpack"

Comment: Did you read through the text at https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/buildpacks#detection-failure (and if so, what buildpack settings have you tried)?

Comment: I'm using the python buildpack and when I tried resetting the buildpack I got an error that it couldn't find the buildpack

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was the stupidest thing. I watched an outdated tutorial that said put no extension after requirements then I looked that you needed a requirements.txt file to continue.