# Can someone please tell me how to rectify this error?

Tags: reactjs, heroku

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1qtXv.png)

I was deploying the react app on heroku but this error is coming. I tried many ways to solve it. But I was unable to rectify it

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. [Please don't post screenshots of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/354577). They can't be searched or copied, or even consumed by users of adaptive technologies like screen readers. Instead, paste the code as text directly into your question. If you select it and click the `{}` button or Ctrl+K the code block will be indented by four spaces, which will cause it to be rendered as code.

Comment: see if this helps  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8216586/git-heroku-pre-receive-hook-declined

Comment: @PapaXVII, that has nothing whatsoever to do with the question being asked here. OP is trying to deploy a React app using a deprecated buildpack. The link you provided is for deploying a _Rails_ app.

Comment: i know, but the problem is `pre-receive hook declined`, not react

Comment: @PapaXVII, no, `pre-receive hook declined` is the _result_ of a more specific error. The more specific error is what actually needs fixing. In this case it's that `heroku-buildpack-static` is no longer supported on the Heroku-22 stack.